# How to do the request dispatch to jetty in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I use nginx for my front web server to serve the static files like .js .css and .html.

However in my page,I have to use the ajax request.

So I tried to create the web service in java and deploy it use jetty.

Now my main application is ran under nginx:

```
   location /mainapp{
        alias   /cygdrive/D/workspace/mainapp/;
        autoindex on;
    }

http://localhost/mainapp
```

Now in my page I have to do some ajax requst like :

```
http://localhost/mainapp/webservice.do/xxx
http://localhost/mainapp/utilservice.do/xxx
```

I have implement these services using java, and deploy them using jetty which can be accessed using:

```
http://localhost:8080/backup/webservice/xxx
http://localhost:8080/backup/utilservice/xxx
```

How to make the nginx dispatch the request to jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the configure file of nginx as following

```
vi /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

location ~ \.(jsp|jspx|do)?$ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```